# Move calculated field title to the top

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have created three containers so that I can change font color individually based on several conditions. I think I have managed to do what I want however, I am unable to move the calculated fields title to the top of my table. Is there any way to easily accomplish that?

I tried playing with the tick "Show innermost level at bottom of view where there is a vertical axis" under table layout, but unfortunately that did not work.
Thank you!

[3 Calculated Fields (Containers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVHby.png)

Comment: I don't understand. What title? Can you post a picture of what you have now?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added a picture. Essentially I added three containers so that I can add logic for coloring based on conditions. I then Edited the axis and changed the title for each. Is there an easy to way to have those titles show up at the top? I tried stacking them on top of each other by turning them into dual axis, but then I end up with a footer I can't get rid of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put your sheet onto a dashboard.  I think it's more flexible about floating titles and hiding axes.